# django: how to override the save() function in a model class so that it displays the saved information in an html template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am new to the django world and web development in general

what I want to do is to preview the data that is saved in one of the created models "Tool"

in models.py

```
class Tool(models.Model):
    text1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text3 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #override code
        super(Tool, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

now I know that I need to override the save() method inside the class Tool but I don't know how it is done?

in veiws.py I did the following

```
from .models import Tool

def preview(request):
    context = {
    "Tools": Tool.object.all()
    }
    
    return render (request,'myApp/preview.html',context)
```

and in preview.html I have the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>{{Tools.text1}}</p>
    <p>{{Tools.text2}}</p>
    <p>{{Tools.text3}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

now from here, how can I render the html inside save() in Tool class?

Comment: i think the question is not clear, from where you will get the data to be saved, what is your follow????

Comment: @MohamedBeltagy I am listing the saved data inside an html template and I want the user to see a preview page that displays the saved data

Comment: Do you mean you want a confirmation page before saving changes to a object?

Comment: @TaipanRex the data is to be displayed in the browser (preview.html) after saving, so the data will be saved anyway, I just want the saved data to be displayed

Comment: then you dont need to override the model `save` method, this should be handled with views. I assume you have a view to create Tool objects. Once the tool object is created, redirect to a view that displays that object.

Comment: @TaipanRex I am sorry, I guess my question was not clear enogh.

the user is entering the fields of Tool in the admin page

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it seems you are using Django Admin to add or change Tool objects. What you want is to redirect the user to the `preview` view after adding and/or changin a Tool. You need to add below methods to your ToolAdmin class:

```
def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
    return redirect('preview')

def response_change(self, request, obj):
    return redirect('preview')
```

Comment: Thanks @TaipanRex, there are no errors but the preview appears empty, do you have an Idea why?

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate over like that :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
{% for tool in Tools %}
    <p>{{tool.text1}}</p>
    <p>{{tool.text2}}</p>
    <p>{{tool.text3}}</p>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, but after this, how can I override save() to show this template on the browser?